# WMF 3 and powershell 2

Tags: .net, wcf, powershell

I have a strange issue on a Windows 2008 R2 server when I try to run PowerShell v2 with v3 installed (.NET framework is 4.5.1 and WMF is 3). On most of my server configured this way, I can just type `powershell -version 2` to switch from v3 to v2, but on a specific server it doesn't work (it simply start a v3) and I can't figure why.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling .NET, going back to version 4.0, uninstalling and reinstalling WMF v3, and finally I tried to go back to WFM v2 but this way I completely lost PowerShell v3.

I noticed that in this server .NET framwork v2 is "not enabled". If I try to start another application requiring .NET 2.0 components I get an error.

[image]

Is there a way to disable/enable .NET framework 2.0? Could it be a problem related to .NET v2.0 not working properly?

Comment: I suppose enabling  framework 3.5 will enable 2.0 (as the share the same runtime): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/08/16/you-must-use-the-role-management-tool-to-install-or-configure-microsoft-net-framework-3-5.aspx